# Emoji renders in MySQL table column and in HTML after ajax, but DOES NOT render after page reload. Why?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, thymeleaf, emoji

I've implemented an emoji picker for comments on my Spring & Thymeleaf web app/blog.

Currently, I can select an emoji, see it appear in the textarea, submit the form, the comment is saved inside the controller post method into my MySQL 5.7.17 db table - I can see the emoji art in the table column- the comment returns via ajax, and I can see the emoji on the page. Yay, woohoo!

But! After I reload the page... I see this:

"ð± and ð¶"

What gives??

In order to insert the emoji's in mysql, I followed this tutorial:

https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

Storing is NOT the problem.

My my.cnf file, located at

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.17/support-files/my.cnf
```

my.cnf:

```
--defaults-extra-file=#
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
```

and then made this query:

```
ALTER TABLE comments CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

and this:

```
mysql> SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec) [then I put: init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4' in the cnf file]

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR 
Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8               |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8               |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8_general_ci    |
| collation_server         | utf8_general_ci    |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

^However, from what I understand, this only works once^

because when I run that command after I Run the app, it reads:

```
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8               |
| character_set_connection | utf8               |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8               |
| character_set_server     | utf8               |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8_general_ci    |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8_general_ci    |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
10 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

My pom.xml has this:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF 8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet" value="utf8mb4" />
    <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" 
    value="utf8mb4"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true"/>
</properties>
```

and on all relevant HTML pages and on the header fragment I have:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

When I System.out.println(comment.getBody()) in the controller's PostMapping method -both before and after I save the comment- I can see the emojis in the terminal just fine! But when I System.out.println(comment.getBody()) in the GetMapping for the page, I see all the weird characters and not the emoji. I'm really confused. What do you think the issue can be and what should I do to resolve it? Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

(From Comment:)

```
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
    `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `body` blob NOT NULL, 
    `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL, 
    `parent_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `post_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `user_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2084 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like 'Mojibake'; see [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

But, since `ð` is hex `F0`, and `F0` is the start of Emoji (etc), it may be that you have specified `utf8` in MySQL instead of `utf8mb4`.  What was `"ð± and ð¶"` supposed to be??

Spring/Hibernate:

Hibernate XML:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8mb4</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
```

Connection url: 
 `db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_nameuseUnicode=true&character_set_server=utf8mb4`

**CREATE TABLE**

`DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8` says that all `VARCHAR` and `TEXT` columns will be `CHARSET utf8` *unless overridden*.

`body blob NOT NULL,` -- You aren't even using a text-like datatype!  `BLOB` says "just throw the bytes in; don't even think about `CHARSET`".

Because of `BLOB`, if the Emoji is going into the `body`, the bytes should be coming out identical to the way they went in.  But, let's check something else.  Please get `HEX(body)`, preferably for a very short body, perhaps with nothing but an Emoji in it.

For example, the hex for  --

```
F09F9881 -- correctly in utf8mb4 (aka "UTF-8" outside MySQL).  Note leading F0
C3B0C5B8CB9CC281 -- "Double encoded".  Might display as ðŸ˜  Note leading ETH (ð)
```

Comment: Hey Rick, thanks for commenting! The emojis were supposed to be a cat and dog but I tested again with the classic smiley. 

```mysql> SELECT body, HEX(body) FROM comments where id = 2077;

| body | HEX(body) |
+------+-----------+
|      | F09F9880  |

1 row in set (0.00 sec)```

Is what I'm getting in Terminal. I placed what you wrote in my XML file and connection url in my application.properties but I still can't see it on the page, ugh. I'm one of those plagued. Should I change the my.cnf file at all? Thanks for your help sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: @RyanH - Something, somewhere, is changing things to "utf8" instead of "utf8mb4".  The "connection url" is the likely place.  Or there could be a `SET NAMES utf8`.  Keep digging around.

Comment: Ok will do, thanks. I noticed this: 

```mysql> SELECT character_set_name FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS`  WHERE table_name = "comments"   AND column_name = "body";
+--------------------+
| character_set_name |
| NULL |
1 row in set (0.00 sec)```

could this be an issue?

Comment: @RyanH - Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE comments`

Comment: Ok: ```| comments | CREATE TABLE `comments` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `body` blob NOT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2084 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |``` Hm, I see that the default character set is utf-8...

Comment: So I altered the database and table: 
```ALTER DATABASE spring_blog_db CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;```

```ALTER TABLE comments CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;```

Then ran the show create query again and now DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

But, just like earlier, the emoji shows up on the ajax response, then goes back to "mojibake" when I reload the page :/

Comment: Those had no effect since there are no character columns in `comments` table.